# How to distribute ros package developed on windows?

Tags: ros, python

I am using ros1 neotic on windows 10 to develop ros package with python. I checked this link [Packaging your ROS project as a snap](https://wiki.ros.org/ROS/Tutorials/Packaging%20your%20ROS%20project%20as%20a%20snap) but it's telling only how to share packages developed on linux machine. How can can I share my package developed on Windows?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately without a well established package manager there's no canonical way to make releases there. You can tag and tell people to build from source. And you can build binaries that you redistribute via windows installers as long as you make sure that they bundle in the necessary dependencies.

The primary ways to release ROS 1 are documented here: http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/ReleasingAPackage (For others future reference ROS 2 release documentation is here: https://docs.ros.org/en/rolling/How-To-Guides/Releasing/Releasing-a-Package.html )

If you release packages into the main distributions and there are two mechanisms to also build and release them onto Windows.

The one where you can most actively participate is via conda forge and the [RoboStack project](https://github.com/RoboStack). It was announced on [ROS Discourse here](https://discourse.ros.org/t/robostack-using-ros-alongside-the-conda-and-jupyter-ecosystems-on-any-linux-macos-windows-arm/20250)

Microsoft also periodically builds a number of packages distributed via the [ROS on Windows](https://ms-iot.github.io/ROSOnWindows/Build/status.html) project where you could contribute to as well.

And if your package is well developed and becomes a core package in the ROS ecosystem it may also be promoted to the main development bundles. But that's a much longer process than what it sounds like you're looking for and would require cross platform capabilities and a large user base.